# Excel formula compare data in two columns, then use data in a 3rd column

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula that will take the value in Col B, find the same value in column C, then input the corresponding value from Col D into Col A.  Here is sample dataset:

```
Col A  Col B   Col C   Col D  
45      cat     dog     12    
12      dog     cats    23    
        fish    cat     45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($D$1:$D$3,MATCH(B1,$C$1:$C$3,0)),"")
```